# VBA to extract value from span class

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I am using vba to extract the value from HTML using the `.getElementsByClassName` but not having much luck at the moment.

I'm trying to extract the "20+" from the following HTML

```html
<p class="delivery-stock">
    <span class="delivery-stock-value">20+</span> 
    <span class="delivery-available f-bold f4">available for delivery:</span>
</p>
<p>
```

The VBA I've used so far is

```
sh01.Cells(r, 5) = HTML.getElementsByClassName("delivery-stock-value")(0).innertext
sh01.Cells(r, 5) = HTML.getElementsByClassName("delivery-stock-value")(0).value
```

and I've done the same using the `delivery-stock` class too.

`delivery-stock-value` & `delivery-stock` occurs only once in the HTML.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Can you share the URL to this site?

Comment: What happens when you run your code?

Comment: Ryan, The url is https://www.toolstation.com An example being https://www.toolstation.com/2-column-radiator/p39711

Comment: Tim, The cell isn't populated because i run the code within On Error Resume Next error handling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an API if available.In this case there is an API you pass the stock code to. This is more efficient and reliable.

**With JSONParser (recommended):**

If you want the security of a JSON parser (e.g. [jsonconverter.bas](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON/blob/master/JsonConverter.bas)) then as follows. Once you add the .bas to your project go to vbe > tools > references and add a reference to `Microsoft Scripting Runtime`

```
Public Sub GetStock()
    Dim json As Object
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://www.toolstation.com/api/products/39711/delivery?site=WW", False
        .send
        Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(.responseText)
    End With
    Debug.Print json("data")("channels")("delivery")("stock")
End Sub
```

**Without JSON parser (not recommended):**

```
Public Sub GetStock()
    Dim sResponse As String
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://www.toolstation.com/api/products/39711/delivery?site=WW", False
        .send
        sResponse = .responseText
    End With
    Debug.Print Split(Split(sResponse, "stock" & Chr$(34) & ":")(1), ",")(0)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you QHarr.  Looking very interesting. Not a method I have tried as yet.  I'll have a look at that tonight. Thanks again. Ian.

Comment: API works a treat.  -Thank you. I can see a whole new API world opening before me. Thanks.

Comment: No worres. APIs are the way to go if available.

Comment: @QHarr As alternative to your analyzing part of http request you may use `WorksheetFunction.FilterXML(sResponse, "//span[@class='delivery-stock-value']"),  if `sResponse` returns a wellformed xml structure.
`

Answer (score 5):

Here's a small example that should return the text to Cell A1 in Sheet1. You want the `outerText` property. This is just for demo purposes, if you want this to be faster and more maintainable, use a web request.

```
Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)

Sub GetTheText()
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim text As String

    With CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
        .Navigate "https://www.toolstation.com/2-column-radiator/p39711"
         Do While .Busy And .readyState <> 4:DoEvents:Loop
         Sleep 1000 ' wait a little bit too
         text = .document.getElementsByClassName("delivery-stock-value")(0).outerText
        .Quit
    End With

    ws.Cells(1, 1).Value = text
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Ryan. Works perfectly.   I was trying to extract direct from the HTML and not loading the url as in your example. Thank you.  Would it be possible to extract from the HTML or do I have to use the CreateObject("internetexplorer.application...etc?

Comment: You have access to all the HTML in the `.Document` in my example. You can grab out what you need in between the `With...End With` section